# How to ssh into ec2 instance running centos as a newly created user?

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I am able to ssh into an ec2 instance as the root user using the private key .pem that was generated when I created the instance.

```
$ ssh -i Desktop/key.pem root@123.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I then created a new user

```
$ useradd dummy
```

When I run the following command to sign in as the dummy user

```
$ ssh -i Desktop/key.pem dummy@123.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I get the following error

```
Permission denied
```

How do I ssh into the new instance as the dummy user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Roman points out, you need to copy the public part of your key (usually ending .pub) to this file: /home/dummy/.ssh/authorized_keys:

```
scp id_rsa.pub root@123.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/dummy/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Note, youll probably have to create the .ssh folder in /home/dummy first.

Then make sure the authorized_keys file has the correct permissions:

```
chmod 600 /home/dummy/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Also, just to be safe, set the Selinux context too:

```
restorecon /home/dummy/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error.  I followed your instructions exactly. **EDIT** Setting the permissions to 700 on .ssh on the remote server resolved it.

Comment: Had the exact same problem today, restorecon saved me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your generated key to the newly created user's `authorized_keys`.